# Upgrade usb 2.0 to 3.0 Dell N4050

Tags: laptop, usb, dell-inspiron, usb-3

My laptop is Dell Inspiron N4050 series. I wanna upgrade my usb port to 3.0 so I bought [this](http://urun.gittigidiyor.com/bilgisayar-tablet/dark-notebook-express-kart-usb-3-0-donusturucu-164231682) But I could NOT connect it to laptop But the saller said to me that It is compatible for Laptop. My laptop's usb slot is like [that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQX1hzQ3Q2MVlkWlk/view?usp=sharing).

And If it is not compatible my laptop where I find the correct component for USB 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

Your *"this"* is an [Expresscard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard).
If your laptop doesn't have an external slot for it, then you cannot use it. I would not expect it to be INSIDE your laptop, so no need to open it up as you have done.

You have found the negative side of having a laptop; expanding the hardware is possible only within the features that the producer has built into it.

Comment: Is there any way to upgrade it without using any external hardwares Just replace the orginal usb to usb3.0

Comment: For that you need to replace the USB2.0 hardware with new electronics, and then create the firmware for it. Not very easy even if you knew enough about it.

Comment: Ok I think that I need a NEW laptop which has USB 3.0 or 3.1

Answer (score 2):

That product looks like it uses an ExpressCard, but according to your [laptop specs](http://www.mega.pk/laptop_products/4369/Dell-Inspiron-N4050.html) it does not have a connector for it, so unfortunately it won't work. That means you're stuck with USB 2 on that laptop, as there is no replacement hardware specified for USB 3.